# Laravel Collection Return

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5.6

I am trying to figure out why laravel 5.6 when you have a collection it prints out the json response paginated than if you are using a normal return response with json on a paginated list. So I have right now this returning in my collection.

```
{
"data": [],
"links": {
    "first": "http://local/api/v3/x?=1",
    "last": "http://local/api/v3/x?=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null
},
"meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "path": "http://local/api/v3/x",
    "per_page": "5",
    "to": 3,
    "total": 3
}
}
```

And what I want it to look like is:

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [],
"first_page_url": "http://local/api/v3/x?=1",
"from": null,
"last_page": 1,
"last_page_url": "http://local/api/v3/x?=1",
"next_page_url": null,
"path": "http://local/api/v3/x",
"per_page": 50,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": null,
"total": 0
}
```

I have tried to use this following code in the collection and it doesnt work, I have found a few functions to get the data I Want but I am still missing most of the data.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\V3;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class DeedTypeCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
public $collects = 'App\Http\Resources\V3\x';

/**
 * Transform the resource collection into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'first_page_url' => $this->links['first'],
        'from' => $this->meta['from'],
        'last_page' => $this->meta['last_page'],
        'last_page_url' => $this->links['last'],
        'next_page_url' => $this->links['next'],
        'path' => $this->meta['path'],
        'per_page' => $this->meta['per_page'],
        'prev_page_url' => $this->links['prev'],
        'to' => $this->meta['to'],
        'total' => $this->meta['total']
    ];
}
}
```

Why does laravel change the default pagination on the collections and how can I fix this to match the default/second dataset.

Here is where the query is built.

```
/**
 *  Function: prepareIndexSelect.
 *
 *  @param: $request - Request sent to controller
 *
 *  Description: Returns queried collection.
 */
public static function prepareIndexSelect($request)
{
    $model = new self();
    $per_page = 50;
    $page = 1;
    $order_by = $model->getKeyName();
    $sort_by = 'asc';

    if ($request->has('per_page')) {
        $per_page = $request->input('per_page');
    }

    if ($request->has('sortBy')) {
        $order_by = $request->input('sortBy');
    }

    if ($request->has('sortByAsc')) {
        $sort_by = $request->input('sortByAsc');
    }

    if ($request->has('page')) {
        $page = $request->input('page');
    }

    return $model->when($request->has('fields'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        self::prepareSelectColumns($query, $request->input('fields'));
    })->when($request->has('includes'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        self::prepareIncludedTables($query, $request->input('includes'));
    })->whereSearch($request->input('search'))
    ->orderBy("{$order_by}", "{$sort_by}")
    ->paginate($per_page, null, null, $page);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where your pagination happens. Laravel does not have a paginate method for collections.

Comment: Updated per your request. basically the normal pagination shows the way I want it but in the collection it changes the format of the output which would through off my api.

Comment: I believe the return is attempting to follow the json api specification. Have a look at eloquent resources: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources. And the specification: https://jsonapi.org/

Comment: Adam I am beginning to think you are right, I have been able to remove the links and meta data but I am unable to extract that information and format my own collection return with that information in a different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the documentation it appears as though you will need to return your derived collection at the respective endpoint.

Your derived resource collection:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class DeedTypeCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
            'data' => $this->collection,
            'first_page_url' => $this->links['first'],
            'from' => $this->meta['from'],
            'last_page' => $this->meta['last_page'],
            'last_page_url' => $this->links['last'],
            'next_page_url' => $this->links['next'],
            'path' => $this->meta['path'],
            'per_page' => $this->meta['per_page'],
            'prev_page_url' => $this->links['prev'],
            'to' => $this->meta['to'],
            'total' => $this->meta['total']
        ];
    }
}
```

Your endpoint:

```
use App\DeedType;
use App\Http\Resources\DeedTypeCollection;

Route::get('/deed-types', function () {
    return new DeedTypeCollection(DeedType::all());
});
```

You may also extend `PaginatedResourceResponse` this should allow you to override `paginationInformation` to format the response the way you need it.

```
protected function paginationInformation($request)
{
    return $this->resource->resource->toArray();
}
```

Then in your derived collection:

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    return (new MyDerivedPaginatedResourceResponse($this))->toResponse($request)
}
```

Comment: The route return and format isnt the problem I am having. The problem I am having is specific to the collection standard return of "data" "links" "meta" I want all this information but not format in that way I want the links and meta information outside of those attributes

Comment: @AlexanderBeyer After digging through the source its possible you may have to override the `toResponse` method. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceCollection.php

Comment: Yeah, you do have to override the toResponse method to accomplish what I was wanting and I dont want to do that for the api. I'll just chalk it up as a restriction to laravel standard, we are trying to stay as out of the box laravel as possible.

Comment: Right from `'data' => $this->collection,` How do you order by attribute (like orderBy('name') )? Also, how do you choose which columns to show?